# Customize DITA: allow p in dt

Tags: dita

I am using the DITA standard.
As a matter of fact, I have to allow p tag in dt.
I want to ban CDTA in the element dt and allow the element p for it.

I changed in file commonElements.mod the following code

```
<!ENTITY % term.cnt 
  "#PCDATA | 
   %basic.ph; | 
   %data.elements.incl; | 
   %foreign.unknown.incl; | 
   %image;
  "
>
```

To

```
<!ENTITY % term.cnt 
  "p | 
   %basic.ph; | 
   %data.elements.incl; | 
   %foreign.unknown.incl; | 
   %image;
  "
>
```

The result is still CDTA in dt allowed and no p tag
On witch dita file I have to make my changes?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Do not change any official DITA files!**
>
> You should create a [specialization](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/os/part3-all-inclusive/archSpec/base/specialization.html#specialize).

You must not allow the `<p>` element in `<dt>`. This violates the specification. Maybe you'd like create a new element that is based on an element that is allowed in `<dt>`. Then you can change the appearance of your new element to *look like* a `<p>` element.

Maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You are right.
I have to create a new element.
Thank you for your suggestion